# How to create a DAG representation for set of operations/workflow?

Tags: workflow, apache-flink, directed-acyclic-graphs, stream-processing

We use apache flink for stream processing. Documentation says, flink generates Execution Graph/DAG based on defined operations(chain of transformations on streaming data). I can also see DAG representation on UI portal.

I'm bit curious how this can be done under the hood. Is there any available library which does this for flink or implemented by Flink itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the execution plan for your job, you can do this:

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
...
System.out.println(env.getExecutionPlan());
env.execute();
```

You'll want to capture this plan at the end of the job, since at that point the job graph has been fully constructed.

It will look something like this:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "Source: Collection Source",
      "pact": "Data Source",
      "contents": "Source: Collection Source",
      "parallelism": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "Map",
      "pact": "Operator",
      "contents": "Map",
      "parallelism": 4,
      "predecessors": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "ship_strategy": "REBALANCE",
          "side": "second"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "Source: Collection Source",
      "pact": "Data Source",
      "contents": "Source: Collection Source",
      "parallelism": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": "Flat Map",
      "pact": "Operator",
      "contents": "Flat Map",
      "parallelism": 4,
      "predecessors": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "ship_strategy": "REBALANCE",
          "side": "second"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "type": "Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed",
      "pact": "Operator",
      "contents": "Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed",
      "parallelism": 8,
      "predecessors": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "ship_strategy": "HASH",
          "side": "second"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "ship_strategy": "BROADCAST",
          "side": "second"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "type": "Sink: Print to Std. Out",
      "pact": "Data Sink",
      "contents": "Sink: Print to Std. Out",
      "parallelism": 8,
      "predecessors": [
        {
          "id": 8,
          "ship_strategy": "FORWARD",
          "side": "second"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented by Flink itself.
If you dive into the code, you will find a `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.JSONGenerator` class which is `@Internal` and has a `getJSON` method. It is used to generate Json representation of a `StreamGraph` instance (Jackson library is involved here). The `StreamGraph` itself represents a whole job topology and may be rendered in a variety of ways.

[Flink sources](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what David said, you can use the `planToDot()` method in the [flink-crawler FlinkUtils](https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/flink-crawler/blob/master/src/main/java/com/scaleunlimited/flinkcrawler/utils/FlinkUtils.java) to convert the JSON he mentioned into a standard graph format (`.dot` file) that can then be opened with any one of several graph visualization programs. Note that this is the logical plan, thus you won't see the results of operator pipe-lining like what's displayed in Flink's web UI.